# How to implement the actions queue in a flux app

Tags: javascript, reactjs, flux

According to Jing Chen (Facebook), they are implementing a similar thing in the upcomming relay framework:

[React.js Conf 2015 - Flux Panel](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=LTj4O7WJJ98&index=17&list=PLb0IAmt7-GS1cbw4qonlQztYV1TAW0sCr)

I'm just curious if someone has implemented something like this into a flux architecture and what does the mental model look like then? As far as I understand you'll create an additional store apart from your "source of truth" store to keep the states of your optimistic updates. Then depending on the feedback from the server you'll take it out of the optimistic store either way and then either merge it into the "real" store or skip the merge and re-render the view. The View displays both what is in the "source of truth" store and what is in the optimistic store, is this order exactly.

If anyone has implemented something like this, it will really great if you can share your experience and mental model for this.

Answer (score 1):

I've been looking for answers here as well. No luck, so I tried to figure it out myself.

So if you listen to what Jing is saying in that segment, I don't think you're maintaining a separate store with mutated state. She's saying to hold on to the optimistic *actions*. She also mentions that undoing those mutations are a pain, and they are. **Keeping track of mutated state is the enemy.**

What she is describing is to cache and validate the actions that the user is taking and **not** how those actions mutate state.

---

So let's take creating a todo item and saving it to the server asynchronously. The goal is to save the actions in the order they happened. And every time the view asks for the todos, apply the mutations on the fly. The view will not know the difference between dirty models or save models because it doesn't need to. But the only time the source of truth is changed, is when the server responds with success or failure.

```
// ........................
// === Add Todo Action  ===
// ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
var addTodoAction = function(todo) {
    var actionId = guid();

    Dispatcher.dispatch({
        actionType: 'ADD_TODO',
        actionId: actionId,
        payload: todo
    });

    // Async Operation (save to server)
    // Callbacks for success and error
    API.addTodo(todo, function(res) {
        Dispatcher.dispatch({
            actionType: 'ADD_TODO_SUCCESS',
            actionId: actionId, // Identify the same optimistic action
            payload: res.todo
        });
    }, function(err) {
        Dispatcher.dispatch({
            actionType: 'ADD_TODO_FAILURE',
            actionId: actionId, // Identify the same optimistic action
            error: err
        });
    });
};





// ................................
// === Private Todos Collection ===
// ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
var _todos = new Immutable.OrderedMap();

// Add todo to collection
var addTodo = function(todo) {
    _todos = _todos.set(todo.id, todo);
};


// ........................................
// === Collection of Optimistic Updates ===
// ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
var _actions = new Immutable.OrderedMap(); // Ordered Immutable Map to preserve sequential order of mutations

// Add action to queue
var addAction = function(e) {
    _actions = _actions.set(e.actionId, e);
};

// Remove action
var removeAction = function(e) {
    _actions = _actions.delete(e.actionId);
};


// ........................................................
// === Create Mutation of Source of Truth for the View ===
// ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
var getOptimisticTodos = function() {

    // Loop through optimistic mutations in order, and apply them to a copy of the state.
    return _.reduce(_actions.toArray(), function(todos, action) {
        switch (action.actionType) {
            case 'ADD_TODO':
                todos = todos.set(action.payload.id, action.payload);
                break;
            default:
        }
        return todos;
    }, _todos.asImmutable());

};



// ..........................................
// === Create a Public API for Todo Store ===
// ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
var TodoStore = _.extend({}, Events, {
    getTodos: function() {
        return getOptimisticTodos();
    }
});

// ......................................
// === Register actions we care about ===
// ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^

/* Example Dispatch 
* 
*   {
*       actionId: 12345,
*       actionType: 'ADD_TODO_SUCCESS',
*       payload: {
*           id: 12345,
*           text: 'Example Todo'
*       }
*           
*   }
* 
*/

TodoStore.dispatchToken = Dispatcher.register(function(e){
    switch (e.actionType) {
        case 'ADD_TODO':
            addAction(e); // add optimistic action to queue
            TodoStore.trigger('change'); // let views know about change
            break;
        case 'ADD_TODO_SUCCESS':
            removeAction(e); // remove optimistic action because it succeeded
            addTodo(e.payload); // add todo to source of truth
            TodoStore.trigger('change'); // let views know about change
            break;
        case 'ADD_TODO_FAILURE':
            removeAction(e); // remove optimistic action because it failed
            console.log(e.error); // handle error in store or elswhere
            TodoStore.trigger('change'); // let views know about change
            break;
        default:
    }
});
```

Comment: I have nothing constructive to say other than +1 for using [DOJOComments](https://github.com/winduptoy/DOJOComments)!